# FBFriendPickerViewController is empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using Facebook SDK for iOS v3.14.1

I have the following code which allocs and inits an `FBFriendPickerViewController`, then presents it.  The second line of code is just COCOS2D's way of presenting a view controller. The view controller itself is being presented okay.

```
FBFriendPickerViewController *friendPicker = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] presentModalViewController:friendPicker animated:YES];
```

**The problem:** The FBFriendPickerViewController is empty when it's presented.

**Things I've tried:**

I've made sure I've requested the proper permissions from the user, i.e. `user_friends`. A call to `FBRequestConnection` with `/me/permissions` parameter, show I have permission to see the user's friend list:

```
permission = "user_friends";
status = granted;
```

I've tried things suggested in other SO questions, but I suspect they're out of date, or at least aren't working for me.

[FBFriendPickerViewController is loading a empty tableview intermittently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757817/fbfriendpickerviewcontroller-is-loading-a-empty-tableview-intermittently)

[FBFriendPickerViewController showing and empty table on iOS. Place Picker running fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530707/fbfriendpickerviewcontroller-showing-and-empty-table-on-ios-place-picker-runnin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `loadData' on your view controller. So, full code is:

```
FBFriendPickerViewController *friendPicker = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
[friendPicker loadData];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] presentModalViewController:friendPicker animated:YES];
```